# Upgrade failure to 20.4

Tags: upgrade

I have been trying to upgrade my Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.4 for a few weeks now. Several times I've gotten the prompt asking me if I want to upgrade. I say yes and nothing happens.

I'm now starting to look into this. I have checked `syslog`, but didn't see anything in it that looked like the problem. Other logs either.

I've tried running `update-manager -c`, but it just presents the prompt again and then nothing...

Advice, please?

Running from the command prompt produces:

```
thomas@Westeros:~$ sudo update-manager -c
[sudo] password for thomas: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
thomas@Westeros:~$
```

But I'm getting the upgrade prompt, so it's not finding uninstalled updates.

Per the comment, I ran `sudo apt full-upgrade` and it found a couple of things to upgrade and forced a reboot. I did so and then re-ran the `update-manger -c` and it behaved exactly as before.

Tried the following:

```
thomas@Westeros:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-browser-l10n gdal-data gimp-data libaec0 libamd2 libarmadillo9
  libarpack2 libbabl-0.1-0 libblas3 libcamd2 libccolamd2 libcharls2
  libcholmod3 libdap25 libdapclient6v5 libde265-0 libepsilon1 libfreexl1
  libfyba0 libgdal20 libgdcm2.8 libgegl-0.4-0 libgegl-common libgeos-3.7.2
  libgeos-c1v5 libgeotiff2 libgfortran5 libgimp2.0 libgmic1
  libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12 libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 libhdf4-0-alt libhdf5-103
  libheif1 libilmbase23 libkmlbase1 libkmldom1 libkmlengine1 liblapack3
  liblqr-1-0 libmetis5 libminizip1 libmng2 libmypaint-1.3-0 libmypaint-common
  libnetcdf13 libogdi4.1 libopencv-core3.2 libopencv-imgcodecs3.2
  libopencv-imgproc3.2 libopencv-videoio3.2 libopenexr23 libpq5 libproj13
  libqhull7 libsdl1.2debian libsocket++1 libspatialite7 libsuperlu5 libsz2
  libtbb2 libtiff-tools libumfpack5 liburiparser1 libxerces-c3.2 odbcinst
  odbcinst1debian2 proj-bin proj-data
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  libodbc1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
thomas@Westeros:~$
```

Is it maybe the package that's `kept back`?

```
thomas@Westeros:~$ sudo apt upgrade libodbc1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libodbc1 : Breaks: libodbc1:i386 (!= 2.3.7) but 2.3.6-0.1build1 is to be installed
 libodbc1:i386 : Breaks: libodbc1 (!= 2.3.6-0.1build1) but 2.3.7 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
thomas@Westeros:~$
```

Comment: Have you fully upgraded your 19.10 system as the message tells you?  ie. `sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: @guiverc, I updated the question with the results of your comment.

Comment: Next I'd check which mirror you are using, and switch if it's not *up-to-date*, ie. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors  (I'd use `sudo apt update` to see which mirror you are using if you're not aware)

Comment: @guiverc posted results

Comment: You must have 3rd party/PPA sources installed; as https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libodbc1 shows you have requirements that will be a problem on *release-upgrade* as current installed packages are different to Ubuntu systems.  You'll likely need to remove the 3rd party packages to make *release-upgrade* possible, unless you want to re-install.  (that condition applies in 20.04 too)

Comment: @guiverc figured it out. See answer below. Would've been nice to get some error message instead of it just dying.

Comment: @guiverc and thanks for the help. You helped unstick me.

Answer (score 4):

The response above said it was keeping back an upgrade to libodbc1. Not know what else to do, I ran `sudo apt install libodbc1` which forced an install of this. After this, I ran `sudo update-manger -c` and hit upgrade and the install started.